# how to make REFrostedViewController work with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am using **REFrostedViewController** library to show side bar menu in my project, which has a tableview to show the content.

When the table cell is selected, I want to show a new page. I want to use UINavigationController to push a new view on top. But it seems that there is no UINavigationController stack in REFrostedViewController context.

How can I achieve UINavigationController behavior to work with REFrostedViewController?

Answer (score 0):

In my setup, the FrostedViewController is the rootViewController right from the beginning. It's contentViewController is my NavigationViewController. In the AppDelegate I did the following:

```
TMSlideMenuViewController *menuController = [[[[self window] rootViewController] storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"slideMenuViewController"];
REFrostedViewController *frostedViewController = [[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.window.rootViewController menuViewController:menuController];

self.window.rootViewController = frostedViewController;
```

In TMSlideMenuViewController, didSelectRowAtIndexPath method you can do this:

```
TMNavigationController* navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tmNavigationController"];

switch (indexPath.item) {
    case 0:
        // Favorites

        frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
        [navigationController pushViewController:sourcesViewController animated:YES];
        break;
```

In order to push a ViewController, you should set the contentViewController to your NavigationController. For me, it worked that way.